# How can i deal with a lot of elements with same animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

My question in the larger case is not specific, but general. Suppose I have a list of elements and I need to animate each of them with the same animation.

For example,

. . . . .

I need to apply fade in animation on each dot with delay.
One way i see, is to create AnimatedController to each dot.
And start each AnimatedController.forward() with delay.

So how can it be, when i have a lot of items with the same animation, maybe there is a bettar way to do something like this (e.g. somehow override one controller for each element)?

Comment: check [Interval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Interval-class.html) class - for more infor see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations

Comment: @pskink Yes, I understand what you mean. I calculated the interval for each point and everything turned out